# RegEx (expresión regular) para validar varios números enteros separados por comas en JS?

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo un campo que solamente permite números enteros sin decimales. Ahora debo modificarlo y necesito insertar varios números así, separados por comas (solamente por comas). Algo como esto:

```
62897,56231,1471,2542,91,32578 ...
```

De modo que necesito una expresión que me permita validar eso. Repito, solamente comas, y solamente números sin decimales.

Gracias!

Comment: Puedes probar en esta web para generar la expresión regular que quieres
http://txt2re.com/, no es complicado, y te permite expresarlo en varios lenguajes de programación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expresión regular es:

```
^(\d+\,?)+$
```

Que cumple con lo siguiente

- Una cadena que inicie y finalice con
- Uno o mas grupos de:

  - Uno o mas números => \d+
  - Posiblemente seguido de una coma ?> \,?

Comment: PERFECTA! Muchísimas gracias elporfirio!

Comment: No es necesario escapar la coma con contrabarra